# Extensions of the ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have differential equation $y'=y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ with the condition $y(0)=0$.
How do we check if the solution is extendable on $\mathbb{R}$? I didn't find anything that could possibly help me with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Which solution do you mean? Trivially you get $y=0$ as solution, which is defined everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's just asked from me to test the extension of the solution on $\mathbb{R}$. I don't think it's meant trivially. I wish I could add more details, but I don't understand either.
Is there something about checking the Lipschitz condition?

Comment: One could also use that the equation is sub-linear, $|f(t,y)|\le 1+|y|$, which guarantees global solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a remark of @Lutzl, the most general solution is as given in the following figure :

[image]

Fig. 1 : *The half parabola can be placed at any positive abscissa, or even be absent (in this case, the solution is function $y=0$).*

Why that ? Either we have a solution which is $y=0$ in a vicinity of the origin (which can be bounded or not), or there exists an $x_0>0$ for which $y(x_0)>0$ ; due to the continuity of function $y$, there is an open interval centered in $x_0$ such that such that $y(x) \neq 0$ ; thus, in this interval, the differential equation can be transformed into $y^{-1/2}{y'}=1$ ; integrate it as $2 y^{1/2}=x+k$, where $k$ is a constant, hence :

$$y=\frac{1}{4}(x+k)^2 \tag{1}$$

Here comes a small case study for "piecing" the solutions :

- either this constant $k$ is $\leq 0$, and we have the solution depicted on the figure (where we have taken $k=-1.5$), by "piecing" the solution $y=0$ and the solution given by (1), and this is the only way to do the "piecing" in this case,
- or this constant $k$ is $>0$, and we cannot fulfill condition $y(0)=0$.

Comment: You can also set $y(x)=0$ for $x<c$ and $y(x)=\frac14(x-c)^2$ for $x\ge c$ for any fixed $c>0$. Note: The equation is autonomous.

Comment: @Lutzl You are perfectly right.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from $y \equiv 0$, $y=\frac {x^{2}} 4$ for $x \geq 0$ and $y=0$ for $x<0$ is a solution on $\mathbb R$.